# Windows Exits Full-Screen Mode when Clicking on Other Monitor

Tags: java, windows, swing, fullscreen

I have an app with two windows. One of them needs to run full-screen on display 2, while the other runs in window mode on display 1. Whenever I click on display 1, the full-screen window is hidden. How can I keep it showing?

I'm using OpenJDK 12 on Windows 10.

My code for creating the full-screen window looks like this:

```
GraphicsConfiguration gc = requestedDevice.getDefaultConfiguration();
JFrame frame = new JFrame(title, gc);
if (requestedFullScreen) {
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    if (requestedDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported())
        requestedDevice.setDisplayMode(requestedMode);
    else
        System.out.println("Diplay Mode Change is UNSUPPORTED!");
    requestedDevice.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.  Ever played a full screen game on with two monitors attached? It's been a while, but, in most cases, the moment you try and interact with the second screen, the full screen exclusive state is disabled.  A better bet, might to make the second window "full screen" instead (ie maximised) rather the FSE

Comment: It's possible. I'm resurrecting code that worked fine on Windows about 12 years ago. Obviously a lot has changed since then...

Comment: Well, given your current experience, maybe it has changed against your favour